# cakephp 2.x: using variables in saveField()

Tags: php, cakephp

so say I want to save only 2 fields with a particular transaction for my system *basically i am taking out items from the inventory stock"

```
public function admin_take($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Inventory->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid inventory item'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->request->data['Inventory']['amount_taken'] < $this->Inventory['Inventory']['amount']){
                amt = $this->request->data['Inventory']['amount_taken'];
                $this->Inventory['Inventory']['amount'] = $this->Inventory['Inventory']['amount'] - amt;
                $this->Inventory['Inventory']['amount_taken'] = $this->Inventory['Inventory']['amount_taken'] + amt;
                $this->Inventory->saveField('amount_taken','x');
                $this->Inventory->saveField('amount','y');
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The inventory item has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            else if ($this->request->data['Inventory']['amount_taken'] > $this->Inventory['Inventory']['amount']) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('request could not be processed, not enough inventory stock to fulfil request .'));
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The request could not be processed, please try again.'));
            }

        }
    } 
    else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Inventory.' . $this->Inventory->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Inventory->find('first', $options);
    }
}
```

is it possible to replace x and Y in the saveField with variables containing the altered data from the arithmetic operations above?

most of the examples I see tend to use actual strings in the saveField $stringValue and if i really need strings? how would i go about with string substitution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer form Dave is indeed correct just alter it and see.
Cakephp already does many database operations and your code does a few to many.

```
$this->Inventory->saveField('amount_taken','x');
$this->Inventory->saveField('amount','y');
```

are 2 operations. better is:

```
$this->Inventory->save(array('amount_taken' =>'x', 'amount' => 'y'));
```

or

```
$this->Inventory->set('amount_taken','x');
$this->Inventory->set('amount','y');
$this->Inventory->save();
```

Comment: dave's answer is correct, but i picked this also for the more efficient manner of going bout with specifically updating a handful of table fields only. thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to replace x and Y in the saveField with variables
>   containing the altered data from the arithmetic operations above?

It is. Just try it, and you'll see it works.

> how would i go about with string substitution here?

Step 1) Replace 'x' or 'y' with your arithmetic operation.  This can easily be accomplished by using your "Copy" and "Paste" shortcuts. (Ctrl+C / Ctrl+P on Windows)

Step 2) Celebrate!